# is onomatopoeia itself onomatopoeic?

Tags: meaning, onomatopoeia

As I note, is the word onomatopoeia itself onomatopoeic? Or does the use of the word not quite follow the rules?

I recall being engaged in a spirited debate about this in my high school days—I cannot recall which side I was on, mind. Nor can I recall who won, or if it was merely settled by accusations of slander at the respective parties' parenthood.

Comment: It's metaonomatopoeic.

Comment: Which is of course hypermetaonomatopoeic in turn.

Comment: No, but the word metaphor is ... a metaphor. Get it? Wild, huh? Is your mind blown yet?

Comment: clever, huh? word.

Comment: I can only suppose some potential closevoters are holding back in a spirit of [seasonal goodwill](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3449/), but I'm aiming for the coveted [Scrooge hat](http://www.google.co.uk/imgres?imgurl=http://www.girlynightout.co.uk/images/uploaded/news/Image/Scrooge%2520Hat.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.girlynightout.co.uk/blog/20101214-christmas-costume-morphsuit&h=300&w=225&sz=14&tbnid=efSVGRJTLIDTPM:&tbnh=91&tbnw=68&zoom=1&usg=__2ubhfs99CC_CN4WjuO3zhV-u0Y8=&docid=erL8UZEbY891NM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HZ_TULaLDfGR0QXUwIFo&sqi=2&ved=0CF0Q9QEwBQ&dur=3580)...

Comment: ...in what sense could *onomatopoeia* possibly be *onomatopoeic?* What on earth is the "sound" it might represent?

Comment: What exactly do you think *onomatopoeic* means?

Comment: the sound it represents is itself... that is, when you say the word, well, there. The sound is made. Much like when you say woof - and what does "woof" mean? Well, "woof" is the literal representation of the sound a dog makes.
What does onomatopia mean? It is the literal representation of the sound that *literally* representing a sound makes.

Comment: @bharal: by that logic, _all_ words are onomatopoeic. What onomatopoeic implies is that you can predict the meaning of such a word by how the word sounds, _without_ already knowing the meaning.

Comment: no, that's not true. "door" means a door, but the sound the word makes isn't in any way related to the concept of a door.
Onomatopoeia means, a word in place of a sound. The sound the word makes *is* related to the concept - because it is the concept.

Answer (score 7):

No.

Onomatopoeia is when the sound of a word evokes its meaning. How exactly does the sound of the word *onomatopoeia* suggest its the meaning? This question sounds like a good way for high schoolers to waste some time, but there's no serious question about the answer.

Comment: well, (and now i might recall where i was in this particular debate) - if you know what onomatopoeia means, how *doesn't* the soud of the word suggest its meaning? 
In fact, the sound of the word is directly tied to its meaning, no?

Comment: The word's [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=onomatopoeia&searchmode=none) confirms this answer and refutes your assertion that the word is based on a sound.

Comment: What sound does an onomatope actually make?

Comment: An onomatope makes a "barroooo, baroooo" sound, but that just seems a bit OT.

Comment: @JLG I'm not arguing that the etymology would imply that the word is based on a sound. I'm asking ~ well, I suppose *now* i'm arguing ~ that the word and the sound of the word neatly coalesce into a respectable (if unorthodox) example of the meaning of the word.

Comment: @bharal then you got the very definition of *onomatopoeia* wrong. An onomatopoeia is *all about* the word being based on a sound *etymologically*. By your definition, every word is an onomatopoeia. In which case there is no need for the term *onomatopoeia* in the first place, because you can just use the term *word*.

Comment: But that isn't  the definition of the word at all, is it? Websters has 2 definitions - the more poingant being
 `the use of words whose sound suggests the sense`
which is the crux of the question